# Is there a downside to using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch in a wildcard?

Tags: css

Are there any downsides to doing this, such a performance, rendering or usability?

```
* {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would downvote this. If there's a reason, could you please comment?

Comment: I feel as if the answer to your question might have a few leads in checking the timelines in the dev tools of each browser on a cacheless refresh with and without that selector in place. Outside of that I'd probably use [GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com) to run a couple of loading tests on them. Offhand I'd say there might be a negligible performance hit (in the average case) since you'd be applying it to stuff that doesn't necessarily have an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is very memory intensive. If your site has very heavy content, I would recommend testing it on old versions of phones/tablets you plan to support to make sure you do not run out of memory and crash your app/browser - I have ran into this issue on some of my apps - if I have this CSS style applied to too many elements, Safari browser will crash when I navigate to certain pages on older tablets with lower memory.